# How to get values from onClickListener outside of onClickListener

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to create a multiple choice quiz, that will generate a fitness program based on your choices. I have three multiple choice buttons, and each time a question is answered, the question and the answers are rotated. I am trying to grab the answer that the user selected for each question, however my program is not allowing me to correctly grab the data.

I have tried using getters and setters but my program still cannot grab the information

```
    private TextView blank;
    private Button mButtonChoice1;
    private Button mButtonChoice2;
    private Button mButtonChoice3;

    String experience;
    String preference;
    int days;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        blank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.program);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);


         mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == "Two"){ 
//QUESTION 1 ANSWER_1
                    updateQuestion();
                    days = 2;


                }
                else if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == "0-6 months") { //QUESTION 2 ANSWER_1
                    updateQuestion();
                    experience = "0-6 months";

                }

            }




          mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == "Three"){ //QUESTION 1 ANSWER_2
                    updateQuestion();
                    days = 3;

                }
                else if(mButtonChoice2.getText() == "6-18 months"){ //QUESTION 2 ANSWER_2
                    updateQuestion();
                    experience = "6-18 months";

                }
           }
       }



          mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == "Four"){ //QUESTION 1 ANSWER_3
                    updateQuestion();
                    days = 4;

                }
                else if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == "1.5+ years") { //QUESTION 2 ANSWER_3
                    updateQuestion();
                    experience = "1.5+ years";

                }
           }
       }



//here i am just testing if my program is able to receive the data that was entered for each variable 
if (day == 2 && preference == "Strength" && experience == "0-6 months") {

    blank.setText("test working");

}
else {

blank.setText("Test not working");

}



}// oncreate
```

However, right when I start the program, before I even choose any of the choices, the test testVIew section already states "test not working".

My program will be able to get the value of the variable if I place the if statement inside the onclickListener function, however, I need the if statement at the bottom because I need to account for all cases of each variable, and cannot put the if statement in the onclick methods.

I WANT TO BE ABLE TO GET THE values of the variables `preference,days,experience` outside of the onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
if (day == 2 || preference == "Strength" || experience == "0-6 months")
```

or

```
if(day ==2 ){
    statements;
}
else if(preference == "Strength"){
    statements;
}
else if(experience == "0-6 months"){
    statements;
}
else {
    blank.setText("Test not working");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate, you juste set the listeners in the button, when you check the answers, the activity is still not displayed on screen. the activity do the checks before you can see the buttons etc because the checks are in onCreate.

You should do the checks after the buttons have been pressed. For instance, in your `updateQuestion()` you detect that the last question has been answered and you make the checks and display the result at that time.